# query designer failed to open in pentaho report designer

Tags: jdbc, localhost, datasource, pentaho, report-designer

Pentaho report designer version - 5.2.0.0-209

Created MySQL data source, **connected**.
MySql Server Details: localhost, port: 3307

checked connection status and queried through phpmyadmin in same localhost server

Getting error while trying to open query designer. Previewing the query typed also getting error-ed out with errors related to connecting to the database.

Error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot connect to MySQL server on localhost:3307. Is there a MySQL server running on the machine/port you are trying to connect to? (java.net.ConnectException)
    at org.gjt.mm.mysql.Connection.connectionInit(Unknown Source)
    at org.gjt.mm.mysql.jdbc2.Connection.connectionInit(Unknown Source)
    at org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.DriverConnectionProvider.createConnection(DriverConnectionProvider.java:140)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog$InvokeQueryDesignerAction.actionPerformed(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:241)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.setVisible(CommonDialog.java:281)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.performEdit(CommonDialog.java:193)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:798)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:71)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.report.AddDataFactoryAction.actionPerformed(AddDataFactoryAction.java:75)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please check if the mysql driver is available in the design-tools>report-designer>lib. I assume that might be causing the issue !!

Comment: already added that in reportdesigner../lib and also db connection test passed